# A regular expression that moves opening { braces to a new line, for C/C++/PHP/etc code

Tags: coding-style, indentation, curly-braces, braces

This kind of code structure makes, IMHO, code less readable:

```
int func() {
  [...]
}
```

It's just a matter of taste, but I prefer this one:

```
int func()
{
  [...]
}
```

So I've trying to make a regular expression to apply in my text editor in order to make code in the first example look like the second one.

I've come up with something like `^([\t]*)([^\t{]*)({.*)$` ( I don't remember exactly if it was like this )
The idea is that when a `{` is found preceded of non-space characters, most probably the function header or a control structure, then split the line and send the `{` to the next line, but preserving the indent level (I.E. the same amount of tabs) of the original line.

The last part, about keeping the indent level is what I can't get right.
Any help appreciated.

--
PS: Feel free to disagree with my coding standards but please remember that's not the main subject here.

Comment: What if an opening brace occurs within a string literal?  Or a construct like "#define BEGIN {"?  It will be very difficult to get this rigorously correct with a regex, though you can probably come up with something that will work 99% of the time...

Comment: Regarding preservation of the indent level, code editors often have an auto-formatting function that will reset all indenting for you. If you have, or can find, an IDE/editor that will do this, then you don't need to worry about that facet of the regexp. (Indeed, you may be able to find a formatter that will do all of what you're trying to do here)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first try.

file.cpp:

```
int main() {
    for (;;) {
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using `sed -r s/^\(\\s*\)\(.*\)\\{$/\\1\\2\\n\\1{/ file.cpp` outputs:

```
int main() 
{
    for (;;) 
    {
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Selecting lines with sed

1. Grab spaces at beginning of line `^\(\\s*\)`.
2. Grab everything else except last opening brace `\(.*\)`.
3. Grab opening brace until end of line `\\{$`.

Substitution

4. Put back 1st and 2nd back references `\\1\\2`.
5. Insert newline and append again 1st back reference.
6. Open brace.